# Maximum of a $j$th derivatives of infinitely differentiable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am wondering how the maximum of a following function $f^{(j)}(t)$ grows with respect to $j\geq 0$:
$$
f^{(j)}(t)=\bigg(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg)^{j}exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}\bigg),
$$
for $t\in(-1,1)$. Any hints or answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there some context to the problem? The j-th derivative should write as  $R_j(t) \exp \left ( -\frac{t^2 }{ 1- t^2 } \right ) $ where $R_j$ is a rational function of $t$

Comment: Yes, that is true. I was reading this paper https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00211-006-0686-x.pdf There is $\Phi(t)$ in the bottom of page 426. And if you look at the inequality (38), there's jth derivative of the function $\Phi(t)$. I need to keep track of how the derivative values grow w.r.t the order of derivatives.

Comment: As a start, you could derive and table a few times the function with wolfram alpha. Then you could try to spot some pattern in the rational part OR ask for the maximum to wolfram and plo them

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Andrea. Actually, I already plotted for j = 1,2,3,4, and it seems the maximum increases exponentially in $j$. But I need a precise order of this exponential growth and also derivation. @asch

Comment: A small improvement of my above form: it's easy to determine the denominator of $R_j$, so that $f^j(t)$ is $\frac{P_j(t)}{ (1-t^2)^{2^{j+1} -2 } } \exp( - \frac{t}{1-t^2} ) $ for some polynomial $P_j$. By derivation one can obtain a recursive law for $P_j(t)$. The local maxima of $f^j$ are found by plugging the roots of $P_{j+1}$ into $f^j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed which not too much accuracy and rounded to the next integer, we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
j & f^{(j)}_{\text{max}} \\
 3 & 507 \\
 4 & 22605 \\
 5 & 1621069 \\
 6 & 167778406 \\
 7 & 39546260573 \\
 8 & 5596238540376 \\
 9 & 1946570701715456 \\
 10 & 797905170925592576 \\
 11 & 191330250571202428928 \\
 12 & 211833943162336317538304 \\
 13 & 95803090255373666286043136 \\
 14 & 97714149961452573928661712896 \\
 15 & 36533843656700087217070299676672 \\
 16 & 73683972772140752088293401069355008
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using a quick and dirty nonlinear regression
$$\log\Big[ f^{(j)}_{\text{max}}  \Big]=-a + b \,j^c$$ with $R^2=0.999968$, we have
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 a & 2.26539 & 0.48656 & \{1.18126,3.34952\} \\
 b & 1.83304 & 0.10211 & \{1.60552,2.06055\} \\
 c & 1.37294 & 0.01865 & \{1.33138,1.41450\} \\
\end{array}$$ for a maximum error of $0.407$ (this is quite large for a logaritmic fit but it gives an idea.